# How to compile so file from Mongodb c++ 2.2 source codes?

Tags: c++, mongodb

Today I try to upgrade my driver for mongodb 2.2. But only get libmongoclient.a file.
The download url is:
http://downloads.mongodb.org/cxx-driver/mongodb-linux-x86_64-v2.2-latest.tgz
Here is my way:

```
scons --prefix=/usr install
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You may find this [discussion thread on mongodb-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/jBVJw-ToHFM) helpful.